# Form API 'image_button' vs 'submit' breaks my AJAX form

Tags: forms

I have an AJAX form that works as expected with the following submit code:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Go'),
);
```

I want to use an image for the button, but the type 'image_button' breaks the AJAX functionality (multiple repopulating select fields, won't appear, or update):

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'image_button',
  '#src' => '/themes/moon/images/go.gif',
  '#value' => t('Go'),
);
```

Oddly, the 'image_button' works fine when clicking it (form works as expected) it's just the AJAX updating of the form that stops working? [Drupal Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)

Comment: Is this a custom form and you bind the '#ajax' property to these submit elements yourself, or is it an existent form that you are trying to customize?

Comment: It's a custom form, but the submit element doesn't even have an #ajax property. Only the first & second select lists have an #ajax property. If anybody wants, I can post the whole form in the question.

Comment: Can you post the code relevant to this issue in the question, so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: Hi @ShabanaBlackborder, over a year later!? I'm not with that company anymore, but if I had to guess they're still working on that project (lol).

Comment: Hehhee, oops, sorry there.  Didn't even see the date!!!

Comment: No worries, I might have a little fault here because I vaguely remember finding a workaround (or fixing it) & I obviously didn't follow up here. So I owe an answer!

Comment: Actually reading it again, I kinda remember using some hacky CSS business to make it a image button; which in turn is probably why I didn't post the non-solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set an unique '#name' tag for EVERY button (submit, image_button, button) on the page. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up that if you are using ctools modals, there is a bug with image buttons such that they aren't submitted when clicked (you can look at your POST details to check what values are submitted). I created a patch here that seems to fix it: https://www.drupal.org/node/1314894

Answer (score -2):

Remove the `#value` from image button..

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Answers here are expected to be of a higher quality than this. Please can you expand on what you mean, and perhaps explain _why_ you feel removing `#value` from the element array will fix the problem

Comment: With only 7 points @modhura doesn't seem to be DSE regular. Perhaps someone else could explain and get theirs accepted instead

Comment: This worked for me when I had 2 x image_buttons, one for 'Submit' and one for 'Preview'. Nothing else worked cross browser except for unsetting #value. I didn't look into why this happens :(